# How do I return all items in a collection that possess an interface property of a specific type?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class ApprovalTicket that has a property called ApprovalRules that is of type IApproval:

```
IApproval ApprovalRules;
```

This field will contain several different types of classes that implement that interface. Now stepping one level up, I will have a List of ApprovalTickets. What I'm trying to do is use linq to return a list of ApprovalTickets that have ApprovalRules of the type MocReviewerApproval.

I was trying something like:

```
var reviews = request.MocApprovalTasks
  .Where(mocApproval => mocApproval.ApprovalRules is MocReviewerApproval)
  .ToList();
```

But when I check the list that gets returned, it's still including tickets that have an ApprovalRules type of MocManagerApproval and others as well. What am I missing?

UPDATE:

Let me be more specific. Here is the inheritance scheme

```
MocApproval : TaskTicket
    >>IApproval ApprovalRules;

MocReviewerApproval : IApproval
MocManagerApproval : IApproval
MocControllerApproval : IApproval


    internal interface IApproval
    {
        bool Approve(Guid approverGuid, MocApproval approval);
        bool Deny(Guid approverGuid, MocApproval approval, TaskComment denialComment);
        bool Close(Guid approverGuid, MocApproval approval, TaskComment closeComment);
        bool Notify();
        void Set(MocApproval approval);
        User GetAssignee();
        TaskComment GetNotificationComment();
    }
```

Comment: Do you inherit from `MocReviewerApproval` in other classes?

Comment: Would you show us your classes and interface signature? (update your question). Also sample input and output, and desired output you want.

Comment: Is this LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Objects or something else?

Comment: updated. @JonSkeet it is just linq to objects

Comment: @Sinaesthetic: Then the *only* explanation is that your diagnostics are wrong. For example, perhaps you're not actually looking at `reviews`?

Comment: I doubt that if there is any problem within your current code, I guess finally you set all of your `ApprovalRules` to `MocReviewerApproval` somewhere in your code, for testing this, just test your linq part with other types, you should get empty list like `mocApproval.ApprovalRules is MocManagerApproval`, ...

Comment: im trying to find it now. I just output all of the Types for the entire list of approval rules without attempting to filter them, and they indeed return as MocreviewerApproval which can't be right because it is still running the correct implementations of things like Approve()

Comment: I think I may have a bum factory loading the wrong rules on instantiation.

Comment: Yep that's what it is... /headslam. The ticket workflow loads the rules based on the stage its in. Unfortunately when you call an old ticket, the NEW rules are loaded. Design flaw. fml. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me. I suspect you've got diagnostic problems, or you're not after the `is` kind of relationship at all. Here's a complete example showing it working:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Foo
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<Foo>
        {
            new Foo { Value = "" },
            new Foo { Value = 10 },
            new Foo { Value = new object() },
            new Foo { Value = new MemoryStream() }
        };

        ShowCount<IDisposable>(list); // 1 (MemoryStream)
        ShowCount<IFormattable>(list); // 1 (Int32)
        ShowCount<IComparable>(list); // 1 (String, Int32)
    }

    static void ShowCount<T>(List<Foo> list)
    {
        var matches = list.Where(f => f.Value is T)
                          .ToList();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} matches for {1}", 
                          matches.Count, typeof(T));
    }
}
```

EDIT: If you want matches which are *exactly* the given type, use:

```
var reviews = request.MocApprovalTasks
                     .Where(task => task.ApprovalRules.GetType() == 
                                           typeof(MocReviewerApproval))
                     .ToList();
```

That's more refactoring-friendly than finding the name as per Servy's original answer.

Comment: I think OP inherits from `MocReviewerApproval` so confused.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: Given the comment on Servy's answer, I suspect that's not the whole story. Unfortunately we're basically in the dark at the moment...

Comment: I just see the comment, yes we're in the dark, just hope if OP shows the signature of classes and interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

`is` means, can be validly cast to, not, "is exactly this type".  In your case, any sub-classes of `MocReviewerApproval` will still return true.  You can use:

```
 mocApproval.ApprovalRules.GetType() == typeof(MocReviewerApproval)
```

to ensure that that type, and only that type, will return true.  Having said that, it's kinda bad code smell to have something like this.  Consider asking yourself if that's really what you want.

Comment: IMO it would be better to use `typeof` for a comparison - see my answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet Agreed, and edited.  It also won't have issues with classes of the same name in different namespaces.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic: That suggests that your diagnostics are wrong. I've given a short but complete example of the code working - can you give a similar example of it not working?

Comment: @JonSkeet, I just saw yours and im running through it right now

Comment: Same results... There may be some flaw in the inheritance scheme? Let me update the post with a bit more

Comment: @Sinaesthetic: It's more likely that there's a flaw in your diagnostics, to be honest.

Comment: This will fail in all cases, just saying. Drop `.Name`.